# Export 3D model from Unity to three.js

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, three.js

I have to create model of human body in WebGL/three.js but I have only Unity model. How I can export model like object or something like this.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to export from Unity to `glTF` and then use `THREE.GLTFLoader` in order to load the asset into your `three.js` app.

The following guide provides more information about loading `glTF` in context of `three.js`:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Use the following Unity3D library for importing and exporting GLTF 2.0 assets:

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF

If for some reasons the `glTF` export from Unity does not work, try it with `FBX` instead.

Comment: I do this with FBX (Using Modo), it works just fine.

Comment: I used this model for both Unity and three.js
https://boxelizer.com/pRender.php?mid=7740369e824e4eadbd83e6f01fa96caa

This loads on the web using the FBX loader, as for unity I used the FBX and then compiled it to a "unity3d" file.